# detectMultiScale hangs when using LBP cascade classifier (OpenCV 4.8.0, C++)

Tags: c++, opencv, freeze, cascade-classifier

**I've trained an LBP cascade classifier for car detection using OpenCV 4.8.0. When I try to use it, the `detectMultiScale` function hangs.**

Here's the classifier:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<opencv_storage>
<cascade>
  <stageType>BOOST</stageType>
  <featureType>LBP</featureType>
  <height>75</height>
  <width>100</width>
  <stageParams>
    <boostType>GAB</boostType>
    <minHitRate>9.9500000476837158e-01</minHitRate>
    <maxFalseAlarm>5.0000000000000000e-01</maxFalseAlarm>
    <weightTrimRate>9.4999999999999996e-01</weightTrimRate>
    <maxDepth>1</maxDepth>
    <maxWeakCount>100</maxWeakCount></stageParams>
  <featureParams>
    <maxCatCount>256</maxCatCount>
    <featSize>1</featSize></featureParams>
  <stageNum>4</stageNum>
  <stages>
    <!-- stage 0 -->
    <_>
      <maxWeakCount>3</maxWeakCount>
      <stageThreshold>-1.0529006719589233e+00</stageThreshold>
      <weakClassifiers>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 5 -232271405 -150405104 -2147270639 -788316039
            -636434134 -922025216 -1996324149 -1170220853</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -8.4758365154266357e-01 6.4864861965179443e-01</leafValues></_>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 8 -217326957 -779419584 -1040187376 1497449481
            -2146905949 -938803005 281788605 -863116279</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -8.3338397741317749e-01 6.5263098478317261e-01</leafValues></_>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 3 -799062757 -706575487 16961969 818069578 -872412557
            -100466555 571088992 -255137189</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -8.5794800519943237e-01 6.8386518955230713e-01</leafValues></_></weakClassifiers></_>
    <!-- stage 1 -->
    <_>
      <maxWeakCount>3</maxWeakCount>
      <stageThreshold>-1.1046675443649292e+00</stageThreshold>
      <weakClassifiers>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 2 -582363137 -268369599 285347019 -642973687 555
            -913309688 -2013011505 -76031825</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -8.5018724203109741e-01 5.8974361419677734e-01</leafValues></_>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 9 -984360501 -2075981309 -1860677159 -1039814568
            -1987469154 165355976 155371681 -8140661</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -8.7958252429962158e-01 5.8119404315948486e-01</leafValues></_>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 10 -1481380181 1233174855 1091111312 -1778179965
            1090585999 -1442633216 1074364613 -661659159</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -8.3567428588867188e-01 6.2639969587326050e-01</leafValues></_></weakClassifiers></_>
    <!-- stage 2 -->
    <_>
      <maxWeakCount>3</maxWeakCount>
      <stageThreshold>-1.0118436813354492e+00</stageThreshold>
      <weakClassifiers>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 6 -913141661 1367671040 134266899 269586464 -2147426165
            -1971322496 -1577058169 -1194221141</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -8.6471664905548096e-01 1.</leafValues></_>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 0 -779271921 -1874788352 268468224 -1322844127 8520
            -2013265408 134226115 -633071478</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -9.2569231986999512e-01 6.8080991506576538e-01</leafValues></_>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 1 -805203965 553715712 50401792 293797891 -1006632832
            1158 1073774632 -1980792702</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -8.2793700695037842e-01 8.2165032625198364e-01</leafValues></_></weakClassifiers></_>
    <!-- stage 3 -->
    <_>
      <maxWeakCount>2</maxWeakCount>
      <stageThreshold>7.8125000000000000e-03</stageThreshold>
      <weakClassifiers>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 7 -2147434368 0 1 805306368 160 -1610612720 3 42336256</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -9.9218750000000000e-01 1.</leafValues></_>
        <_>
          <internalNodes>
            0 -1 4 65538 37120 16 -2147483648 -2147483648 1 1 1208635408</internalNodes>
          <leafValues>
            -9.8839455842971802e-01 1.</leafValues></_></weakClassifiers></_></stages>
  <features>
    <_>
      <rect>
        1 51 15 6</rect></_>
    <_>
      <rect>
        3 6 9 6</rect></_>
    <_>
      <rect>
        4 51 13 6</rect></_>
    <_>
      <rect>
        5 54 5 4</rect></_>
    <_>
      <rect>
        8 59 8 5</rect></_>
    <_>
      <rect>
        14 28 24 13</rect></_>
    <_>
      <rect>
        28 43 21 10</rect></_>
    <_>
      <rect>
        30 53 13 4</rect></_>
    <_>
      <rect>
        50 29 15 12</rect></_>
    <_>
      <rect>
        66 48 8 3</rect></_>
    <_>
      <rect>
        80 64 5 3</rect></_></features></cascade>
</opencv_storage>
```

And this is my code:

```cpp
CascadeClassifier cascade;
if (!cascade.load("path\\to\\cascade.xml")) {
  cout << "Failed to load classifier" << endl;
  return -1;
}

Mat frame = imread("path\\to\\test\\frame.jpg");
cvtColor(frame, frame, COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
equalizeHist(frame, frame);

vector<Rect> cars;
classifier.detectMultiScale(frame, cars);  // execution freezes here

for (const auto& car : cars) {
  rectangle(frame, car, Scalar(255, 0, 0), 2);
}

namedWindow("Detections", WINDOW_NORMAL);
imshow("Detections", frame);
```

**As I can see from the debugging data, the execution freezes at the `detectMultiScale` call.**

The XML file is loaded properly — `load` returns `true`.

*UPDATE:* this message might be relevant here. It appeared after training stage 3 (fourth if you count from 1).

> Required leaf false alarm rate achieved. Branch training terminated.

However, as stated [here](https://answers.opencv.org/question/84852/traincascades-error-required-leaf-false-alarm-rate-achieved-branch-training-terminated/), that's not an error and my cascade will still work. Despite that, I tried training a new classifier with more data to fit (200 positive samples per stage), as advised on the webpage above, which produced the same result.

An acceptable solution would be either a C++ implementation that uses my current cascade properly or instructions on training a new, usable cascade.

Comment: does the exact same code *not-hang* on any other xml file you can find? [mre] implies debugging, which includes determining such things.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Strangely, it didn't hang when I tried using the pretrained `lbpcascade_frontalface.xml`. I didn't modify my XML after it was generated by `opencv_traincascade`! Included it in the question.

Comment: if that tiny xml file is the result of your training, the training failed. check the parameters you're requesting. a decent cascade has more substance than that.